# Could not cast value of type 'NSSplitViewController' (0x7fff8fbe20c8) to 'AppName.ViewController' (0x100049988)

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, toolbar, nswindowcontroller

I created a cocoa web browser. I added a `NSSearchfield` in my toolbar. I was testing it out then I got and Error saying `Thread 1: Signal SIGART`. In my debugger, it said

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSSplitViewController' (0x7fff8fbe20c8) to 'AppName.ViewController' (0x100049988).
```

This is happening because I linked the window controller to a split view controller instead of the viewcontroller. This is the code I got an error in

```
  var viewController: ViewController {
            get {
                return self.window!.contentViewController! as! ViewController
                // Error here
            }
        }
```

I have tried doing this

```
var SplitView: SplitViewContorller {
            get {
                return self.window!.contentViewController! as! SplitVC
                // Error here
            }
        }
```

But then I get numerous errors saying

```
Value of type 'SplitVC' has no member 'webView'
```

In this code

```
 var urlStr = searchFieldToolBar.stringValue
        if urlStr.hasPrefix("https://") {
            let url = NSURL(string: urlStr)
            let req = NSURLRequest(url:url! as URL)
            self.viewController.webView.load(req as URLRequest)
        }
```

I don't know how to fix this.

Can you please help me

Comment: In the line of `self.window!.contentViewController! as! ViewController`, how many times are you force-unwrapping variables?

Comment: I'm unwrapping it about 10 times

Comment: First, name the view controller starting with a capital letter.  Second, what is its class, NSViewController or NSSplitViewController?  Third, if you are going to show code, start with the class name right from the top instead of showing two or three lines.

Comment: ViewController: `NSViewController`, SplitVC: `NSSplitviewController`, WindowController: `NSWindowcontroller`